# photo sharing in social sites through android intent

Tags: android

I have tried to share photo through social network sites that are installed in the android mobile phone generally using android intent. the following is my code.

```
package com.example.final_share;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b;
String path="https://...some url path"
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

            sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));

        }
    });

}



}
```

But the problem is only my status is uploaded not the image. Anyone can help me with this? if i want to fetch images from webserver and try to share those data how will i do this?

Comment: Did you try using `setType("image/jpeg")` instead?

Comment: if i add this tag the system crashes when i want to share some .png photo

Comment: With which exception?